# Accessing v-for dynamically created elements outside of loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I've got a v-for loop and I would like to access the dynamically created item outside of loop. Is it possible?

```
    <li v-for="item in cart.items">
      <h1>{{ item.product.name }}</h1>
    </li>
    <p>{{ access item.product.name outside }}</p>

   data () {
      return {
        cart: {
          items: []
        },
        products: [
          {
            name: "name"
          },
          {
            name: "name2"
          }
        ]
      }
   }
```

Comment: *which* item did you want to access? Do you see the problem? of course, if you know (eg, the first) it should be `cart.items[0].product.name`

Comment: I would like to access all the items so I can display the quantity of them all.

Comment: Then surely you need another `v-for` to loop over `cart.items` again. Or perhaps `item.product.quantity` within the existing loop. Its not clear what you're trying to *achieve*

Comment: So I used the computed method and worked it out. 
      quantityTotal() {
        var quantity = 0;
        this.cart.items.forEach(function(item) {
          quantity += item.quantity;
        });
        return quantity;
      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to access all the items so I can display the quantity of
>   them all.

That is a data operation, not a DOM operation. You don't get your data from the DOM. It is in your viewmodel. As you figured out (and noted in your comment), you can make a `computed`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get access from the parent. You can put the v-for on a template tag, and do your iteration there.

```
<template v-for="item in cart.items">
  <li >
    <h1>{{ item.product.name }}</h1>
  </li>
  <p>{{ item.product.name }}</p>
</template>
```

This allows you access to each item. See: [Templates and v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt)